# Can I use single `force:recordData` for both Add & Update record?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-data-service

I have a requirement where I need to insert and update a contact. Now, I am using `force:recordData`.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="ldsContact"
     recordId="{!v.selectedUserId}"
     layoutType="FULL"
     mode="EDIT"
     targetRecord="{!v.record}"
     targetFields="{!v.imContact}"
     targetError="{!v.recordError}" />
```

When I try to **edit** a record, it is working fine, but when I try **adding**, it gives following error:

> We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help.

I understand, that the above error is most likely due to the `recordId` attribute and as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_create_record.htm)

> To create an empty record from a record template, you can’t set a
>   recordId on the force:recordData tag. Without a recordId, Lightning
>   Data Service doesn’t load an existing record.

So, my concern is, I don't want to repeat myself just because of the above issue and use another `force:recordData` just for adding a new record, as there is a huge work associated with the one I am already using. Any way I could use **one** `force:recordData` for both **Insert** & **Update**?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, why cann't you use 2 `force:recordData` and base them on the same attributes? what is the 'huge work associated with the one I am already using'?

Comment: Each `force:recordData` has around 10 fields, absolutely same, and their CSS, customization, JS, and opening them in a pop up are few details of the work I was referring to. In the JS controller of my cmp, I am referring the fields through `aura:id`, and since there are many behaviors associated with the fields which aren't gonna change whether I add or edit, but with 2 `force:recordData` I would need to repeat the code in JS and CSS and also the mark up. I hope that clarified your question.

Comment: OK, but if you create another `force:recordData` you can still use the same attributes - no need to duplicate

Comment: I didn't really think of that, but now it makes sense. If put this as an answer, and if possible, explain it with an example as well, it would be helpful for other readers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add another [force:recordData](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordData/specification) without the id, and use the same attributes inside both of the components:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="ldsContactEdit"
     recordId="{!v.selectedUserId}"
     layoutType="FULL"
     mode="EDIT"
     targetRecord="{!v.record}"
     targetFields="{!v.imContact}"
     targetError="{!v.recordError}" />

<force:recordData aura:id="ldsContactAdd"
     layoutType="FULL"
     mode="EDIT"
     targetRecord="{!v.record}"
     targetFields="{!v.imContact}"
     targetError="{!v.recordError}" />
```

This way you do not need to add more work, just use your current one, and you can choose in your javascript controller if to use `ldsContactAdd` to add a record, or `ldsContactEdit` to edit one.